# How to open Modal based on a function that changes the useState boolean in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have the following useState and function:

```
const [displayTraits, setDisplayTraits] = useState(false);

const feelingsFilled = () => {
  const keysToCheck = ["anxiety", "mood", "cognition"];
  function validate(obj) {
    try {
      if (
        Object.keys(obj)
          .filter((key) => keysToCheck.includes(key))
          .every((key) => obj[key].counter > 0)
      ) {
        setDisplayTraits(true);
      } else {
        setDisplayTraits(false);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  }

  validate(daily);
};
feelingsFilled();
```

which I then try to hook up with a modal so that when my function `feelingsFilled()` return true and changes the `displayTraits` to true, then it will open.

```
<Modal isVisible={displayTraits} />
```

I am trying to run this but get the following error

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Comment: It will rerender everytime you change the state. 

Since you run feelingsFilled() on every render, it will then run setDisplayTraits, which will cause it to rerender. That explains your errormessage

Comment: @thsorens Thank you for your reply, I just edited my code a bit to what I think it would be but I think the same thing is going on.  How can I run my function just once?

Comment: You dont need to use state for this. You simply just want to make a render based on a calculation. feelingsFilled can just return true or false, instead of setDisplayTraits.

If you somehow needs to change the state variable based on some change of data, you can use useEffect(() => {setYourStateStuffInHere}, [someDatastructureYouwantToTriggerThisEffect]);

Comment: @thsorens hmm okay, I thought because my program is checking every time to see if the case is true, that it would need to change state.  How would you suggest I proceed from here, just do the calculation in the isVisible area for the modal?

Comment: It depends on where the data you are using to compute this comes from. If daily changes, then you wound need to recompute based on that. I will add an answer for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would need to make some assumptions on where the daily data comes from. If it is a changing prop or some other state, you can compute stuff based on that.

Using some state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  //computeYourStuffAndSetState
  const result = validate(daily);
  setDisplayTraits(result);
}, [daily]);
// The array param is a change-listener
```

Then you can bind your <Modal visible directly to the state variable, instead of a function.

Another example is to not use state at all and compute it everytime daily changes.

```
const showModal = useMemo(() => {
  return validate(daily);
}, [daily]);
```

useMemo and useEffect is a part of the built in react hooks.

Or you can just do something like:

```
const showModal = validate(daily);
```

This will also work, but will be less performant as it will recompute on every render

Comment: Okay I see thanks, I'l ltry the second option.  So for when showing my modal, i'll just pass it the constant 'showModal' that you have above? For your first example with the useEffect, I would then pass it setDisplayTraits correct?

Comment: yes, and for useEffect, you would pass it the displayTraits property from your useState in your sample